# link key to a bash script

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to link a button (now without function) to a bash script that I have made on UBUNTU. I'm using a clevo W150HNM/Sager NP5160

I want to use 1 or 4 for this, see photo:

[image]

I don't get any output of `xev`, `getscancodes` or `cat /dev/input/eventX` when pressing this key.

How can I use this key to run the script?

Comment: crossposting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11691/4485 I vote to close this one, since the discussion already started on U&L

Comment: If xev doesn't give any output, it might mean that it's interpreted specially in hardware and must be read by something other than keyboard tools.

Answer (score 2):

If the button works in Keyboard Shortcuts, then you can assign the button to your shortcut.

(Keyboard Shortcuts is in System->Preferences).