# Link button to script

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to link a button(now without function) to a script that I have made. I'm using a notebook with several extra buttons

This button however is like the power on button, it stands by itself and is not part of my keyboard.

I don't get any output of xev, getscancodes or cat /dev/input/eventX when pressing this button.

How can I use this button to run the script?

Many thanks
Simon

Comment: More information, please.

Comment: Notebook? Vendor? What language do you use?

Comment: I'm using a clevo notebook W150HNM
is there something else in particular you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

This topic is discussed in these two questions:

1. [key bindings - link key to a bash script](https://askubuntu.com/q/36098/13398)
2. [Bind key to a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11691/6709)